# Prime Rib versus New York Strip Roast

Tags: roasting

i recently cooked a bone-in, 6 lb Prime Rib roast using the "5 minute per lb @ 500F then closed oven for 2 hours" method and it came out absolutely PERFECT!  mediuam rare and delicious.

http://allrecipes.com/recipe/221958/chef-johns-perfect-prime-rib/

i have a boneless, 11 pound New York strip roast and was wondering if the same method and calculations can be used to create the same medium rare perfection?  i dont want to take any chances on overcooking this expensive roast!

thank you for your help

Answer (score 5):

I know many people say the same thing over and over for questions like this, but: **Probe thermometer**.  They aren't expensive.  You can set them for a temperature so that you pull your roast at *exactly* the doneness you want.  (Well, generally pull it a few degrees below that, and let it coast upward while it rests.)

Heat transfer to roasts does not mathematically work out very well for "time per pound" formulas -- generally these only seem to "work" for a certain range of weights, but they don't work in general.  Adding in an uncontrolled "leave oven shut" (presumably turned off?) makes the method even more prone to imprecision.

Bottom line: Use a probe thermometer.  It makes no sense to risk screwing up a $100+ cut of beef rather than buy a $20 thermometer which you can reuse every time and always be certain of results.